How to track a route through leaflet/openstreetmaps markers?
I have a map in a delivery app that shows all the customers locations where I need to delivery products.
Here is the component's part where I need to render the map:
<div className='card-aguardando card-bairro-mapa'>
                                <div className='card-header'>
                                    <span className='span-card-header'>{bairro.bairro}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div className='card-body text-center' id='card-body-mapa'>
                                    {jsonPedidosAgrupados.length > 0 && <MapContainer id='map map-container' center={[jsonPedidosAgrupados.find(ped => ped.nbl_bairro === bairro.bairro).nbl_latitude, jsonPedidosAgrupados.find(ped => ped.nbl_bairro === bairro.bairro).nbl_longitude]} zoom={14} style={{ height: "155px", width: "100%"}}>
                                            <TileLayer
                                                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                                                attribution="&copy; <a href='https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright'>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
                                            />
                                            <Marker position={[empLatitude, empLongitude]} icon={redHouseMarkerIcon}/>
                                            {Object.entries(pedidosGrouped).map(([key, pedidos]) => (
                                                <Marker key={key} position={[parseFloat(key.split(',')[0]), parseFloat(key.split(',')[1])]}>
                                                    <Popup>
                                                        {pedidos.length > 1 ? `${pedidos.length} pedidos aqui:` : `${pedidos.length} pedido aqui:`}
                                                        <ul>
                                                            {pedidos.map((pedido) => (
                                                                <li key={pedido.nbl_id}>#{pedido.nbl_num_nota} - {pedido.nbl_endereco}</li>
                                                            ))}
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </Popup>
                                                </Marker>
                                            ))}
                                            <FullscreenControl />
                                        </MapContainer>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>

This map is adding markers correctly, but I wish I could track a route through those markers and keep updating the best path as the delivery car moves.
I really have no idea about how I can do that (or if its even possible with this API, or if I should change it). So, if anyone know some examples that I can study or some answer id be glad.
Btw, I tried to adapt to my problem this solution that I saw in a community, but I keep getting an error

Map container not found

or

Map container already exists

useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (mapRef.current) {
            mapRef.current.remove();
            mapRef.current = null;
            console.log('existe');
        } else {
            console.log('não existe');
        }

      if (jsonPedidosAgrupados.length > 0 && !mapRef.current) {
        mapRef.current = L.map('map').setView([empLatitude, empLongitude], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
          attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(mapRef.current);

        const waypoints = [
          L.latLng(empLatitude, empLongitude),
          ...Object.entries(pedidosGrouped).map(([key]) => {
            const [lat, lng] = key.split(',').map(Number);
            return L.latLng(lat, lng);
          })
        ];

        const routingControl = L.Routing.control({
          waypoints,
          createMarker: (i, waypoint) => {
            if (i === 0) {
              return L.marker(waypoint.latLng, { icon: redHouseMarkerIcon }).bindPopup('Company');
            } else {
              return L.marker(waypoint.latLng).bindPopup(`Order ${i}`);
            }
          }
        }).addTo(mapRef.current);

        routingControl.on('routesfound', (e) => {
          console.log('Route found:', e.routes[0]);
        });

      }
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
      if (mapRef.current) {
        mapRef.current.remove();
        mapRef.current = null;
      }
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [jsonPedidosAgrupados, empLatitude, empLongitude, pedidosGrouped, redHouseMarkerIcon]);



2 hours and 11 views. stackoverflow is over
